# click method not supported for safari 6

Tags: ruby, selenium

I want to write automation script in selenium with ruby for safari(version 6).but the click method of selenium is not supported for safari version 6 so there any other way to click the selenium element.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Javascript instead to do the same. Following is the Java equivalent to produce a click. You should be able to convert it to Ruby.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    String script =
        "var elem = document.getElementById('element_id');"+
        "if( document.createEvent) {"+
        "var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');"+
        "evObj.initEvent( 'click', true, false );"+
        "elem.dispatchEvent(evObj);"+
        "} else if( document.createEventObject ) {"+
        "elem.fireEvent('onclick');"+
        "}";
    js.executeScript(script);
```

[**Reference**](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2067)

Ruby equivalent will be something like

```
script =    "var elem = document.getElementById('element_id');"+
            "if( document.createEvent) {"+
            "var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');"+
            "evObj.initEvent( 'click', true, false );"+
            "elem.dispatchEvent(evObj);"+
            "} else if( document.createEventObject ) {"+
            "elem.fireEvent('onclick');"+
            "}";
driver.execute_script(script);
```

PS: I am a Java guy and not so familiar with Ruby.

Comment: but i want to write script in ruby not in java and i am also using execute_script() method which gives the same response.

Comment: your answer is working in case of java but thanks for giving the hint of logic, which now I apply in ruby.

Comment: @reshma: Glad I could help! You can accept this answer if it helps you or add your own answer